Using Telebit for SSH
I have only recently gotten into setting up a Linux server so I will try my best to describe the problem here. I have installed Telebit no problem and I setup ownCloud to work with it as well, all of this works however, after I followed the instructions to setup ssh with Telebit, when I would try to ssh from my Windows machine into my server I would get my-name@url.telebit.io: Permission denied (publickey)..
I have also tried to setup a public key but I would still get the same error as above even though I'm 99% sure I set that up properly. Ideally, I would like to ssh into the Linux server without publickeys but doesn't really matter much to me I just want to be able to ssh into the server when I am away from home. Anyone know how to fix this?
Edit: Using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. I used ssh-keygen on Windows in command prompt to generate the keys and transferred the key over by sshing into the machine using the lan IP, I should make it clear that I can ssh into the machine when on the same network using the local IP without Telebit.

What version of Ubuntu?

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

"transferred the key over by sshing into the machine using the lan IP" ... what exactly did you do in this step? Which files were modified and how?

The output of ssh -G my-name@url.telebit.io | grep -E '^(user|hostname) ' might be helpful. However if I understood how this Telebit works correctly, the error message is coming from your router, not from your Ubuntu machine (you can double check this by veryfing SSHD logs on the Ubuntu machine) and you'll probably have to forward the SSH port you're connecting to from your router to your destination machine.
